# Concatenate lines with similar key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python, but I don't have lot of experience in programming.
I'm trying to build a routine to import a CSV file and iterate each line in which there's an specific key and concatenate those lines in one single line.

**Example**:

CSV file:

```
'0001','key1','name'
'0002','key1','age'
'0001','key2','name'
'0002','key2','age'
```

The resulting file should be:

```
['0001','key1','name','0002','key1','age']
['0001','key2','name','0002','key2','age']
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the CSV:

```
import csv

with open('my_csv.txt', 'rb') as f:
    my_list = list(csv.reader(f))
```

At this point, my_list presumably resembles a list of lists, such as the following::

```
[['0001', 'key1', 'name'], ['0002', 'key1', 'age'], ['0001', 'key2', 'name'], ['0002', 'key2', 'age']]
```

Create a dict, with each key[number] from the lists corresponding to a key in the dict, and with each value in the dict corresponding to the concatenated lists for a particular key:

```
dict_of_lists = {}

for item in my_list:
    _, key, _ = item
    if key in dict_of_lists.keys():
        dict_of_lists[key] = dict_of_lists[key] + item
    else:
        dict_of_lists[key] = item
```

**If you don't care about the order of the list items:**

```
dict_of_lists.values()
```

Output:

```
[['0001', 'key2', 'name', '0002', 'key2', 'age'], ['0001', 'key1', 'name', '0002', 'key1', 'age']]
```

**If you care about the order:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(sorted(dict_of_lists.items())).values()
```

Output:

```
[['0001', 'key1', 'name', '0002', 'key1', 'age'], ['0001', 'key2', 'name', '0002', 'key2', 'age']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to store all entries in RAM, using a defaultdict to create 'buckets' of entries by key would be a way to do this (this assuming a file called 'file.csv'):

```
from collections import defaultdict

#this defaultdict acts as a Python dictionary, but creates an empty list
# automatically in case the key doesn't exist
entriesByKey = defaultdict(list)

with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        #strips trailing whitespace and splits the line into a list
        # using "," as a separator
        entry = line.rstrip().split(",")
        #the key is the second field in each entry
        key = entry[1]
        #concatenate entry to its respective key 'bucket'
        entriesByKey[key] += entry

#Now, we create a list of concatenated lines by key, sorting them
# so that the keys appear in order
out = [entriesByKey[key] for key in sorted(entriesByKey.keys())]

#pretty-print the output :-)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(out)
```

The output for this program for your input would be:

```
[["'0001'", "'key1'", "'name'", "'0002'", "'key1'", "'age'"],
 ["'0001'", "'key2'", "'name'", "'0002'", "'key2'", "'age'"]]
```

All that's missing would be to strip the single quotes for each entry (and maybe format the output to your liking instead of just using `pprint()`). If you can guarantee that your input is well-formed and that fields consistently have single-quotes (or, more precisely, that the first and last characters for each field in an entry are never relevant) you may do so by adding the following above the `key = entry[1]` line:

```
entry = [field[1:-1] for field in entry]
```

This will strip the first and last characters of each field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your csv file does not contain the single quotes (and those are only for presentation here) this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',header=None,dtype=str)
Result = Data.groupby(1).apply(lambda y: ','.join([s1 for s2 in y.values for s1 in s2]))
f = open('Result.csv','w')
for r in Result:
   f.write(r+'\n') 
f.close()
```

the output is stored in Result.csv